# In Asp.net using C#, how can I convert ==head== __italic__ and others to html equivalents?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was able to save the following in database

```
==heading===

Some __useful contents__ and **bold texts** here
```

I want to output `==heading==` to `<h1>heading</h1>`

`__useful contents__` to `<i>useful contents</i>`

`**bold texts**` to `<b>bold texts</b>`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) for this purpose (same is used here, in SO).

You can get package that will convert markdown to HTML [here](https://github.com/Knagis/CommonMark.NET) in for C#. Or if you want client browser to render it (to save CPU on the server) you can use [this](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) JS plugin.